# ¿Como puedo hacer un print (imprimir) a los registros de una tabla de base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, print, imprimir

mi problema es que intento hacer un print , imprimir una tabla de base de datos , para poder pasarlo a hojas de oficio ,basicamente imprimir la tabla , lo intente con

```
<button onclick="window.print()" class="btn btn-success btn-raised btn-xs">Imprimir</button>
```

me lo imprime pero imprime toda pestaña y solo quiero que imprima la tabla que contiene los registros de una base de datos , y que pueda seleccionar los campos que se impriman , ya que quiero evitar que se imprima tambien los botones , adjunto imagen de referencia :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con CSS y media queries puedes elegir qué imprimir y qué no. [Este ejemplo](https://sympli.io/blog/a-quick-guide-to-css-for-printable-webpages/) (en inglés) puede servirte de guía.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo,me funciono!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente la impresión de datos los maneja el lado del servidor en tu caso lo debe de hacer PHP y no javascript.

Para eso debes hechar mano de librerias que ya realizan ese trabajo como [PHPSpreadSheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) o
[DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

Puedes revisar su documentación y si tienes alguna duda recuerda realizar otra pregunta y no seguir en el mismo hilo.

Comment: Okey!! Muchas gracias!! Eso hare!